# Parsing data from file application C#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I am making c# application to read in files and parse data into a list or array using a space. The data being passed in from the files is in columns, hence why array or list needs to separated by a space so I can access it to manipulate.

```
namespace FixtureReports
{
    public partial class btnFileSelect : Form
    {
        // contructor
        public btnFileSelect()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        // this will do the verification 
        private void btnVerify_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // clear textbox each time its clicked
            results.Clear();

            //store each file path into a string
            string nailAssignmentResult = textBox1.Text;
            string nailFixtureResult = textBox2.Text;
            string nailContactResult = textBox3.Text;

            // error for if all three paths are empty 
            TextBox errorMessage = results;
            if (nailAssignmentResult == "" && nailFixtureResult == "" && nailContactResult == "")
                errorMessage.Text = "ERROR: Cannot have empty path for all three reports!!";

            // verifying each file path exists
            if (File.Exists(nailAssignmentResult))
                errorMessage.AppendText("Nail Assignment Report Found");

            if (File.Exists(nailFixtureResult))
                errorMessage.AppendText("\r\nNail Fixture Report Found");

            if (File.Exists(nailContactResult))
                errorMessage.AppendText("\r\nNail Contact List Report Found");


            // grab each file and iterate through each of them 
            var files = new[] { nailAssignmentResult, nailFixtureResult, nailContactResult };

            foreach(var file in files)
            {
                // parse the contents into a list separated by a space 
                List<string> lines = File.ReadAllLines(file).ToList();
                

                foreach (var line in lines)
                {
                    // for each line of data, what needs to be compared
                    if (line.StartsWith("*"))
                    {
                        continue;
                    }



                }
            }

        }

        // prompt for file selection
        private void nailFixtureBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            OpenFileDialog openFileDialog = new OpenFileDialog();

            if (openFileDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                textBox1.Text = openFileDialog.FileName;
            }
        }

        // prompt for file selection
        private void nailAssignmentBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            OpenFileDialog openFileDialog = new OpenFileDialog();

            if (openFileDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                textBox2.Text = openFileDialog.FileName;
            }
        }

        // prompt for file selection
        private void nailContactBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            OpenFileDialog openFileDialog = new OpenFileDialog();

            if (openFileDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                textBox3.Text = openFileDialog.FileName;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am unsure if I should be reading the data into a list or array since it needs to separated by a space and I will be comparing data from within the text files. I am kinda stuck because I know what I need to do going forward, just unsure how to do it.

Comment: According to the [Sysstem.IO.File.ReadAllLines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.readalllines?view=net-8.0) documentation: _**Returns**: String[]_. According to [foreach statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/statements/iteration-statements#the-foreach-statement): _The foreach statement executes a statement or a block of statements for each element in an instance of the type that implements the System.Collections.IEnumerable or System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T> interface_.

Comment: According to [Arrays (C# Programming Guide)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/arrays/#array-overview): _...All arrays implement IList, and IEnumerable..._. There's no need to convert the data returned by _File.ReadAllLines_ to a List. Also see: [Built-in types (C# reference)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/built-in-types).

Comment: The following may be of interest: [Introduction to classes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/types/classes) and [Explore object oriented programming with classes and objects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/tutorials/classes).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understand ultimately you need to work with a single cell value, then you can avoid storing it in List/Array.

Converting to a list and then needing to again process further to get a single value would cost somewhat similar.

Since File.ReadAllLines(file) is already providing you with string[ ] which contains all your lines (assuming they are well distinguished in text files with carriage returns), you can directly loop over those lines and split each line to work on the data element or a cell value.

```
string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(file);

foreach (string line in lines)
{
    // split each line to get single element
    string[] values = line.Split(" ");

    foreach (string val in values)
    {
        // your logic
    }
}
```

I hope this provides an alternate approach for your problem.